# Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuefire

I've been having troubles with my Vue app that utilizes firebase. I have now gotten the snapshot working correctly and am receiving an object that I convert into an array. Only problem is when I try to filter the object I get I get a "Cannot read property "indexOf" of undefined" The function prints out the array normally and visibly it looks just like what I need, I just can't access it with the includes. Worth mentioning that if I enter a 0,1,2,3 instead of i it doesn't throw the error.

Here is my Vuex exporter with the snapshot of my Firebase

```
const users = db.ref('users')

users.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  store.state.lawyers = Object.values(snapshot.val())
  console.log('called')
})
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lawyers: '',
    selectedLawyerIndex: 1,
    selectedCategory: 'Contracts'
  },
  getters: {
    getLawyers: state => {
      console.log('state ' + state.lawyers)
      return state.lawyers
    },
    getCurrentLawyer: state => {
      return state.lawyers[state.selectedLawyerIndex]
    }
}
```

and the function causing the error:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cat: this.$store.getters.getCurrentCategory,
      lawyers: this.$store.getters.getLawyers
    }
  },
  components: {
    appLawyerWidget: LawyerWidget
  },
  methods: {
    filteredLawyers () {
      var arr = []
      console.log(this.lawyers)
      for (var i = 0; i < this.lawyers.length; i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lawyers[i].catarray))
        if (JSON.stringify(this.lawyers[i].catarray).indexOf(this.cat) >= 0) {
          arr.push(i)
        }
      }
      return arr
    }
  }
}
```

any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Okey I somehow got it to work by removing the .catarray and instead just indexing the whole object.

Comment: I dont know much about Vue, but maybe look at the end of your array, or through all of the elements if short enough. [`JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)

Comment: `this.$store.getters.getCurrentCategory` where this getter?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(this.lawyers[i].catarray).indexOf(this.cat)` not good. Try `var cats = JSON.stringify(this.lawyers[i].catarray); if (cats.indexOf(this.cat) >= 0) ... `

Comment: You realize `JSON.stringify` returns a string? It just so happens that `indexOf` is also a string method, but i don't think that's what you're intending. Also, it's undefined because vuex is not reactive in `data`. All vuex data should be in `computed`.